# Installing Dependencies SciKit/NumPy/SciPy

Tags: linux, unix, python-2.7, gcc

I'm trying to install SciKit learn on a Red Hat Server.  According to [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/install.html) on Scikit-Learn's website, I can run the following command on Red Hat to install the the dependencies.

```
sudo yum -y install gcc gcc-c++ numpy python-devel scipy
```

However, I don't have root privileges, so I am wondering if I can some how modify the above command to run the command?

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot modify the package base of your system since you are not root and not in sudoers list.

However, you can try to build that packages from sources, but I'm sure that you  will come across a lack of `*devel` packages but you will not manage to install them due to the same reason.